# How to work with multiple pages project with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying create-react-app recently,I found that it can only process one default page , which called 'index.html'.I want to know ,if  my project is multiple-pages , can I develop my front-end with create-react-app?How?
I know I can use react-router to do my job ,however , I still want to find a way to process multiple pages with create-react-app. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not wrong. Probably You are just confused between multiple page app and Single page application. You need to understand and use `react-router` module along with ReactJS. React router provides routing capability to a react application. (Since using react you are creating a SPA Single Page Application).

For more and indepth information, have a look at this link:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: Thanks! Let me try!